# Indexing a file using f.tell() in python

Tags: python, file-io, for-loop

I'm trying to index a huge sized file with each line consists of 5 columns. The first column is going to be the key and it's sorted (Let's say we have only 17 of those). I want to generate a dictionary which tells the starting position of each key value.  so what I do is the following:

```
fmaps = open('file.txt','r')
pos = fmaps.tell()
ln = fmaps.readline()
chrDict = {ln.split()[0]:pos}



for ln in fmaps:

    if not chrDict.has_key(ln.split()[0]):
           pos = fmaps.tell() 
           chrDict[ln.split()[0]] = pos
```

However, when I try opening the file and

```
f = open('file.txt','r')
f.seek(val)
print f.readline()
```

I see that the positions are completely off to the point except the first one which is 0 byte from the begining.

Does anyone know what the iteration in the for loop does to the position in the file?

Comment: "...the positions are completely off" What does this mean? Show the output you get and what would be your expected output. Also what's `val` in your last piece of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python does internal buffering when using a file object as an iterator and that will skew the result of tell(). Just keep using readline instead. Also,

(edit: oops, i didn't read your question right the first time!)

- follow @falsetru's advice and read binary
- you don't need to special-case the first read

This should do the job:

```
chrDict = {}
with open('file.txt','rb') as fmaps:
    while True:
        pos = fmaps.tell()
        ln = fmaps.readline()
        if not ln:
            break
        key = ln.split()[0]
        if key not in chrDict:
            chrDict[key] = pos
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [`file.tell` documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes#file.tell):

> **Note** On Windows, `tell()` can return illegal values (after an `fgets()`) when reading files with Unix-style line-endings. Use binary
>   mode (`'rb'`) to circumvent this problem.

Replace the mode `'r'` with `'rb'`.